# How to make .htaccess nested redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, nested

How to make .htaccess nested redirect?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It does redirect from `/?id=url` to `/url`, but does not redirect `/1/2/3/?id=url` to `/1/2/3/url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the second line: `^$` matches an empty string, so only the root (like `/?id=X`) is redirected. You have to add `.*` to match all URIs:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}%1? [R=301,L]
```